# I'm looking to get completed events counts but this query not working

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My query

```js
let findEvents = await eventModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      participants: {
        $eq: event.userId
      },
      eventStatus: {
        $eq: "COMPLETED"
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalEvents: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      completedEvents: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                "$attendants",
                event.userId
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

In this query the if condition is not working, not able to fetch userId from attendents array where userId exists. Could you explain why ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and also your `event.userId` input.

Comment: unwind the attendants array before the group stage.

Comment: mine event.userId is "623c6dc2eedb2c4c9719a7fe" and check sample data in image link: https://wystap.s3.amazonaws.com/Screenshot+(94).png